# How can I change all text to Americanized spelling using Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two websites, one for the UK and one for the US, both of which use the same text in some places, spelled in the British way - e.g. "I specialise in optimising stuff"

Is there a Javascript/JQuery package/solution to automatically replace all the British spelling that it finds in the DOM, to American spelling? E.g. change the above to "I specialize in optimizing stuff"

So I suppose I could loop through the DOM elements and replace them, eg

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace('ise', 'ize');
    $(this).text(text); 
});
```

But this won't work in all cases, e.g. "wise" should not be changed to "wize". Are there any known regex or similar solutions to solve this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have a solution. Please edit your question with clarification, examples, and code you tried so far (even not working one)

Comment: @PeterThoeny thanks. Yes, I've included some code now which indicates an approach that could be used (though it is flawed)

Comment: I added the question back for review to be reopened

Comment: You should really add a complete set of changes. What with words like "colour", "analyse", "travelling" (double L), "manoeuvre", "paediatric", "licence",.... and what with words that just are completely different, like "aubergine", "biscuit", ... This is too broad.

Comment: "*Are there any known regex or similar solutions to solve this?*" - nothing short of an actual dictionary, no.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution that uses a translation table and some jQuery and native JavaScript to traverse the DOM and to change text, excluding tag attributes. Click on the **Switch to USA Spelling** button:

```js
const translations = {
  colour: 'color',
  colours: 'colors',
  Colour: 'Color',
  Colours: 'Colors',
  optimising: 'optimizing',
  specialise: 'specialize'
};
const regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + Object.keys(translations).join('|') + ')\\b', 'g');
console.log('regex', regex);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.switchSpelling button').click(function() {
    $('#mainContent *').contents().each(function() {
      if(this.nodeType == 3) {
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(regex, m => {
          return translations[m];
        });
      }
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.switchSpelling {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 70px;
}
.grayBackgroundColour {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
.yellowBackgroundColour {
  background-color: #fffff0;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainContent">
<div class="switchSpelling">
<button>Switch to USA Spelling</button>
</div>
<h1>The history of Colour</h1>
<div class="grayBackgroundColour">
<h2>Colours in Renaissance</h2>
<p>We specialise in optimising and restoring colours</p>
</div>
<div class="yellowBackgroundColour">
<h2>Colours in Cubism</h2>
<p>We specialise in optimising and restoring colours</p>
</div>
</div>
```